# Accept Rejection Mante carlo simulation and simulation mean

Tags: normal-distribution, monte-carlo, accept-reject

I read that in Monte Carlo simulation results, the larger the sampling, the mean sample results from the simulation close to normal distribution, but does this also apply to Monte Carlo accept rejection ? or in Monte Carlo accept rejection, the larger the sampling, the closer the mean sample density is to the target distribution?

Comment: Accept-rejection is just a simulation method used to produce a sample of size $n$, $n$ being the (fixed or random) number of accepted values. The average of that sample converges to the expectation with $n$, almost surely.